# I can reach GitHub from guest account only

Tags: network, catalina

I can't reach `github.com`; the DNS resolves but then the connection times out (on Safari, Firefox and Chrome). I'm running macOS 10.15.5.

I've run `sudo dscacheutil -flushcache` and `sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder`, to no avail.
See [this superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/1559142/github-com-resolves-but-times-out) for all the debugging I've done so far

I'm asking a separate question here because one key clue is that when logging in with my laptop's guest account, I can reach github.com. If I create another admin user account however, the issue is still there.

For that reason I'm wondering: **what are the networking-related settings that would apply to regular users but not the guest account?**

**Edit** Adding more debugging info

- `dig` output showing that DNS resolves:

```
$ dig github.com
; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> github.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 54977
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;github.com.            IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
github.com.     59  IN  A   140.82.112.3

;; Query time: 109 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Tue Jun 09 22:07:32 CEST 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 55
```

- Request timing out in `curl`

```
$ curl -v --insecure -L 140.82.112.3
*   Trying 140.82.112.3...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 140.82.112.3 (140.82.112.3) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: 140.82.112.3
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.1
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Content-length: 0
< Location: https://140.82.112.3/
<
* Connection #0 to host 140.82.112.3 left intact
* Issue another request to this URL: 'https://140.82.112.3/'
*   Trying 140.82.112.3...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 140.82.112.3 (140.82.112.3) port 443 (#1)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
  CApath: none
[...TLS handshake details]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=US; ST=California; L=San Francisco; O=GitHub, Inc.; CN=github.com
*  start date: May  5 00:00:00 2020 GMT
*  expire date: May 10 12:00:00 2022 GMT
*  issuer: C=US; O=DigiCert Inc; OU=www.digicert.com; CN=DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: 140.82.112.3
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.1
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Content-length: 0
< Location: https://github.com/
<
* Connection #1 to host 140.82.112.3 left intact
* Issue another request to this URL: 'https://github.com/'
*   Trying 192.30.253.113...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connection failed
* connect to 192.30.253.113 port 443 failed: Operation timed out
* Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Operation timed out
* Closing connection 2
curl: (7) Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Operation timed out
* Closing connection 0
* Closing connection 1
```

If I curl without `-L` (i.e. without redirects) then I do get to the site, and get the HTML back:

```
$ curl -H "Host: github.com" --insecure -v https://140.82.112.3/
...
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
...
```

Comment: Check your proxy setup for each user.  However, when you say “DNS resolves...” it means DNS is working.  A connection timing out means it didn’t make the connection.  Flushing DNS cache won’t work here.  So, the question is...how did you determine DNS was resolving?  If you issue the command `dig github.com` what do you get back?

Comment: @Allan I don't have any proxies set up. I used `host` to determine that DNS was resolving.  I added the `dig` output to the question.

Comment: So, it’s not a DNS issue.  You got an authoritative answer back.  The issue is in the last part of the the `curl` output.  There’s a redirect to 192.30.253.113 that times out.  Now, what you’re saying is that if you create a new user this doesn’t happen?  Can you post the `curl` output of  the exact command that succeeded under the different user?  And you’re using the exact same command - correct?

Comment: @Allan the issue doesn't happen on the macOS guest user (which is Safari-only, so I can't `curl`). I created a new admin user, but the issue is still happening there, with the same redirect to `192.30.253.113` (that URI does belong to github, according to whois services I looked at).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix was given by the answer to https://superuser.com/questions/1559142/github-com-resolves-but-times-out

My /etc/hosts had the 192.30.253.113 IP for github.com; that IP probably became invalid recently. Removing that line fixed the issue.